# Connection is closed exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm new to C# and trying to establish a C# db connection. But I'm getting an exception.

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

following is the code

```
public void executeCommand()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", con);

    try
    {
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    rdr.Close();
   // rdr.Close();
}
```

and this is my connection string

```
public static string connectionString = 
    "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=service;User Id='mayooresan';Password='password';";
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: You shouldnt have try/catch blocks with nothing in the catch part. Thats the best way to hide exceptions. Always use at least  a Debug.writeline(ex); Maybe your connection is not being made, and its silently being catched, so you cant see it ....

Comment: You should remove all of the try/catch blocks from this code.  In the first one, you're swallowing the exception.  That's a terrible idea.  Exceptions contain useful information about why something went wrong.  My explicitly ignoring helpful error messages, you deny yourself the ability to fix them.  The second one isn't handling the exception in any way, so why bother catching it?  As a general rule of thumb, only catch an exception when you are ready to _handle_ that exception.  If the context has no means of handling it, don't catch it.  Let it bubble up to the parent context.

Comment: Additionally, look into `using` statements for disposable resources (such as `SqlConnection`).  It basically creates a try/finally block for you, and `finally` blocks are the proper place to dispose of such resources.  Otherwise you can have a resource leak in your application if and when anything fails.  (Take particular note of the try/finally construct.  Not every `try` needs a `catch`.  As I said before, there's no need to catch exceptions you're not going to handle.  `try` can have just a `finally` for disposing resources and reacting to events accordingly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most *probabbly* connection object fails to open a connection, but as you are catching it, you can not figure out the error. To be clear:

```
try
{
   con.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); //ADD THIS STRING FOR DEBUGGING, TO SEE IF THERE IS AN EXCEPTION.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped thanks :) I had a invalid connection string dat was the isue :)

Answer (score 3):

You are catching any exceptions when opening the connection. Most likely the connection is not opening and is throwing an error. Remove the try/catch at the opening of the connection and you will probably see why the connection is not open

Comment: It's obvious why it cannot be opened: because it was never closed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't close the connection and reader when an exception was raised, therefor you need to use the `finally`-block of a try/catch or the [`using-statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which closes implicitely:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
    {
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something with it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apart from that you should not use empty catch blocks. If a connection cannot be opened, it cannot be used. Then you should log that and throw the exception, but don't act as if nothing had happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping everything in one try-catch block. As it stands now, if an exception is thrown when you try to open the connection, it will fail silently. Try this code instead:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", con);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Or, in this case, just don't use a try/catch block at all.  Since the exception isn't being handled, there's no reason to catch it in the first place.

Comment: This leaves him room to add real error-handling later. You should never leave code that can throw exceptions willy-nilly

Comment: Who said anything about "willy-nilly"?  If he wants to add logic to handle the exceptions, then he can add a try/catch block later.  But there's absolutely _no_ point in catching an exception *only to re-throw it and do nothing else*.  If the code in the current context isn't in a position to _handle_ the exception, then it shouldn't catch it.  Let the exception bubble up to a context that _can_ handle it.  Throwing exceptions isn't a bad thing.  Catching them for no reason is.

Answer (score 1):

are you debugging the code?
if not, you wont be able to see the exception because you don't have anything on your catch

Also I suggest this approach to use on your scenario:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
}
```